# Rewrite from .. where .. select to more compact one

Tags: c#, linq

This is the code:

```
public DateTime GibSomeStartDate(IEnumerable<int> partnerNumbers, DateTime startTime)
{
     return (from contract in this.databaseContext.Contract
             where partnerNumbers.Contains(contract.Pnr) && contract.SomeDateTime >= startTime
             select contract.SomeDateTime).Min();
}
```

`databaseContext` Instance is child of `Entity Framework` `DbContext`

My refactorings objectives:

- make it compact
- check if `from where select` finds nothing. In this
  situation `Min()` will cause an Excetion

Comment: I wasnt sure whether this question for this site or fot http://programmers.stackexchange.com If I have post it on the false one - migrate it please. Thank you.

Comment: Well, what should the function return if `partnerNumbers` is empty?

Comment: @Leonid partnerNumbers cannot be empty

Comment: thank you for your answers - have upvoted all of you )) I ll mark the one I find the best next days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
public DateTime GibSomeStartDate(IEnumerable<int> partnerNumbers, DateTime startTime)
{
     return this.databaseContext.Contract
                .Where(c => c.SomeDateTime >= startTime && partnerNumbers.Contains(c.Pnr))
                .Min(c => (DateTime?)c.SomeDateTime) ?? DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

**Edit:** Stole the `(DateTime?)` idea from Jesse C. Slicer's answer, but didn't modify the function signature. You can also return `DateTime.MaxValue` if that is more useful to you, or you can go with his idea of returning `DateTime?`, in which case you don't need that at all.

Comment: it doesnt work. "System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`".

Comment: It doesnt work cause of condition in my answer: "check if from where select finds nothing. In this
situation Min() will cause an Excetion"

Comment: @MikroDel - Wait... you *want* it to throw the exception?  Why do you need to refactor it, then?

Comment: the Exception was cause I have wrong parameter ) Your answer is good

Comment: It might be worth considering swapping the order of the date comparison and the contains check inside the where clause, particularly if `partnerNumbers` is expected to be a large collection.

Comment: @DanLyons - Good suggestion. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished with a slight modification to your method signature and an extension method:

Here, the signature now can return `null` if there are no records selected:

```
public DateTime? GibSomeStartDate(IEnumerable<int> partnerNumbers, DateTime startTime)
{
    return (from contract in this.databaseContext.Contract
         where partnerNumbers.Contains(contract.Pnr) && contract.SomeDateTime >= startTime
         select contract.SomeDateTime).SafeMin(someDateTime => (DateTime?)someDateTime);
}
```

This extension method will trap `Min`'s exception and return `null` instead:

```
public static U? SafeMin<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, U?> selector) where U : struct
{
    try
    {
        return source.Min(selector);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of changing the signature, but I don't like the extension method.  Better to not throw an exception in the first place than to throw and catch one.

Comment: I'd agree in the case that the exception occurs frequently. But if it's a super-rare occurrence (the `where` always filters to at least one item), then there's no harm, no foul. In the other case, you're always having to do a conditional check, which may be expensive over the long haul.

Comment: you'll have to download all the dates to client in order to find the minimum value. And having a try/catch as a control flow is not a good approach. Use `DefaultIfEmpty` instead

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely as I don't know how it (download all dates to the client) would be different from using the regular `Min` supplied by LINQ. Are you saying that rather Peter Kiss' solution, which doesn't use `Min` is the right way to go for performance's sake?

Comment: Throwing an exception is a heavy cost stuff, try: return source.Any() ? source.Min(selector) : null; but you still have to download all dates as almaz said.

Answer (score 2):

Not compact but it will not cause an exception:

```
public DateTime GibSomeStartDate(IEnumerable<int> partnerNumbers, DateTime startTime)
{
     return (from contract in this.databaseContext.Contract
             where partnerNumbers.Contains(contract.Pnr) && contract.SomeDateTime >= startTime
             orderby contract.SomeDateTime descending
             select contract.SomeDateTime).FirstOrDefault(); //default(DateTime)
}
```

Comment: This might be slower than a good old Min.

Comment: Yes it might be, but if you have an index on that table with columns Pnr and SomeDateTime it can be far good enough.